# Magento 2 product quantity increasing automatically

Tags: magento2, auto-increment, stock, product-quantity

I have magento 2.2.7, the issue is when I update product quantity to zero "0", it automatically increments the quantity after some time. I tried on 3 products and each products increment was different.
I checked in logs, none were generated, checked product update time, that too also isn't changing after automatic increment. Any guesses, how can resolve it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. Just commented out sales_clean_orders cron in vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/crontab.xml